# Why does iTunes autostart when Bluetooth headphones are connected?

Tags: macos, audio, bluetooth, itunes, headphones

When I connect the Bluetooth headphones to the MacBook Pro iTunes starts automatically. I wish to stop that. How do I do that?

The second best solution is that Spotify autostarts instead.But I really prefer that nothing happens.

- MacOS: 10.14
- iTunes: 12.9.0.64
- Headphones: Sennheiser PXC 550

Comment: You will find several solutions in [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/86315/prevent-itunes-from-opening-when-connecting-bluetooth-headset). Some of them may not work in the latest OSX, so I suggest to start with the least-destructive ones and undo the ones that don't work. The last entry in [this post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2570254) is more explicit for one of these solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I have OSX 10.14.4 and [this solution](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/98462/330424) worked for me (Creating an empty Automator App, then replacing iTunes with that).

It would let me replace iTunes just like that, but after booting into recovery, mounting my disk there, it would let me do it in the recoveries Terminal. (No `csrutil disable` required!)